# Angular.js Lazy Loading

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading

Im using the angular.js 1.5.8 framework along with "oc.lazyload" library for lazy loading applications.
Now, i'm trying to load a "child" component from parent component (ie. lazy load the component "navigation" into the "main") but it doest work.

Main component:

```
angular.module('app', [
        'ngRoute', 'oc.lazyLoad'
    ]).component('main', {
        template: '<navigation></navigation>',
        controller: function($ocLazyLoad: any) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load('ui/navigation.js');
        }
    })
)
```

Navigation.js:

```
angular.module('app').component('navigation', {
    templateUrl: './ui/navigation.html'
});
```

When i look into the developer console it shows me that only the navigation.js file is loaded and not the template (navigation.html)

It does work when i'm using it with ngRouter resolve property however. Is there anything similar i could use for components?